# how to drill aligned holes in steel pipe?

Tags: pipe, drill

I need to accurately drill multiple holes in steel pipe (1.25-2" diameter, 65-100 mil wall thickness, about 10ft long).    I need to drill a half-dozen or so evenly-spaced aligned pairs of holes all the way through the pipe.    So the two holes in each pair need to be diametrically opposite.   And the pairs need to be radially-aligned - I'm not sure how best to describe this: maybe, if a line is drawn through each pair of holes, those lines should all be parallel (to each other).

Is it possible to do this with reasonable accuracy using home tools, or is a machine shop necessary (e.g. a milling machine) ?   How ?

P.S. For background: I want to extend the height of a wood railing (it consists of multiple 2x2 balusters with a 2x6 board at the top).   I plan to do this by screwing 3/8 x 10" hanger bolts into the top of the 2x6.  Then attach the steel pipe to the machine-threaded top of the hanger bolts, with acorn nuts at the top and hex nuts underneath the steel pipe.   This is my solution to: [extend height of wooden railing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/156157/extend-height-of-wooden-railing/156222#156222).   Once the pipe is drilled, I can then use it as a jig for drilling the pilot holes in top of the 2x6 (for the tapered-thread end of the hanger bolts).   Perhaps I should consider wooden dowel instead of steel pipe; easier to drill, and cheaper (when I screw up).

Comment: Sounds like you need at least a drill press.  Even the smaller ones should handle a 2" pipe.  Are you ok with that? (less than $100)

Comment: I'd rather figure out how to do it without; OTOH it's not clear that's enough.    It should be easy enough to make diametrically-opposite marks on one end of the pipe; and a pair at the other end.   If I could just get those two pairs aligned with each other, then I could pop two chalk lines down the  length of the pipe.

Comment: You'd need some kind of jig, then, to hold the bit perpendicular to the pipe face.  The issue is that you have nothing to guide the bit inside the pipe, so if your jig has any wiggle to it (which it probably will), you could end up with less-than-perfect holes.

Comment: When the pipe is laying on the ground, the contact patch with the ground is a straight line.  My concern is getting the hole exactly straight through the pipe.  You could make some home made jigs, but at some point your time and the accuracy of the project is worth more than a $75 drill press that you could sell to recoup some expense later.

Comment: Maybe the two holes need to be drilled separately, using two lines marked down either side of the pipe.  But how to draw those lines ?

Comment: The drill press should make it easy to get a pair of diametrically-opposite holes, but how to get the pairs of holes aligned with each other (so imaginary lines drawn though each pair are all parallel) ?

Comment: If you clamp the pipe to a flat surface, you can just run a marker along where the pipe meets the surface.  Any holes along that mark will necessarily be collinear, as long as your pipe doesn't slip.  If you drill through the pipe perpendicular to the pipe face, your holes will be both diametrically opposed and collinear.

Comment: Kinda the line (no pun intended) I was thinking.   Clamp to a perfectly flat and straight surface (wherever I can find that).   Maybe just use that to get the two ends of a chalkline.   Then make two diametrically-opposite marks for the other chalkline.    Drill the two holes in each pair separately.

Comment: Problem with a chalk line is getting the ends aligned to the same points on the circumference.

Comment: some pipes have printing on them from the manufacturer .... the printing could be used as a straight line ....... also the pipe may have a seam down its length that could be used as a straight line

Comment: first, make sure that the drill bit is vertical ..... use a jig described in the answer below .... drill a hole clear through the pipe at one end ...... push a straight metal rod through the hole that you just drilled  ..... make sure the rod is vertical when drilling the other holes

Comment: another way is to draw a line on the side of the pipe ...... clamp a piece of wood to the end of the pipe so that it forms a tee ..... the wood will keep the pipe from rolling sideways when the pipe is laid on the floor and dragged ..... make a jig that holds a marker pen against the side of the pipe .... have someone drag the pipe along the floor so that the pipe slides past the marker .... the marker will draw a straight line on the pipe

Comment: Yeah, the pipe I'm thinking of using, I believe the steel yard called hot-rolled but also said it had a weld down the length of it.   And that weld is probably pretty straight.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this project has two main issues - getting all the through-holes in the same plane on the pipe, and making a straight hole all the way through a pipe.

To draw a straight line on the pipe, you can set the 2" pipe on the flat ground (like the floor of a garage) and place a common (straight) 1x4 board next to it.  Run a marker along the corner formed by the board touching the pipe and you'll have a straight line.

For drilling the straight holes, you can either buy a [drill press](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HQONFVE) (random example) or you can make a jig.  The drill press is pretty self explanatory, so here's an idea for a jig.

```
 Drill bit
   !
  _!_ top plate
 | ! |
 | ! |
 | ! |
 |_!_| bottom plate
 |/ \| - hole for pipe
_|\_/|_ footing
_______
```

Now, with my amazing artwork out of the way....  You make this structure with some 2x4 lumber and use a steel plate (thin is fine) on the top of the "top plate" and "bottom plate". The total hight of the jig will be about 11".  The square at the bottom should be just big enough for the pipe to fit in to keep it centered.  Get a 12" long drill bit and drill through the jig as straight as possible measuring as much as you can.  This pilot hole will make or break your jig.  The steel sheets/plates will help keep the bit centered over the long run but are optional if you don't have many holes to drill (the wood of the jig will *waller* out after repeated use). If you can get a perfectly straight hole, you should be good to go!  insert the pipe and get to drilling.

Comment: Not quite following.   But I think it'd be easier to drill the two diametrically-opposite holes separately, if I could just mark it properly.   You describe a good way to get a line down one side of the pipe (in your 2nd paragraph, above).   Then at each end, make two marks diametrically opposite the two ends of that 1st line; use those marks to draw the 2nd line.

Comment: Improved the picture a bit?  Sorry, it's clear in my head.  The issue with having marks on each side of the pipe is still going to be getting each hole straight.  Maybe a little angle to each hole won't matter for you, but if you're drilling a 1/4" hole and expecting to push a 1/4" rod through them, they both have to be perfectly straight and aligned.  Going at it from both sides would be way too hard in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I see now.   Looks like this will get you one nice straight diametrically-opposite hole-pair.     But when you slide the pipe through the jig to where you want the next hole-pair, how do you insure it's at the same point on the circumference ?   Using the line you've drawn before ?

Comment: You would make a mark on the side of the jig in the center (in line with the drill bit) and make sure the line you drew lines up with that center mark.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, I think you'll at least need a drill press.  But it really depends on exactly how accurate you need it.

In any case, I'd work it like this:

1. clamp a straight piece of lumber to a flat table.  Should be at least as long as the span between the furthest holes.  Lumber must be <= half the outside diameter of the pipe.  Close to half the diameter is ideal.
2. Clamp the pipe against the edge of the lumber.  Draw a line down the length of the pipe with a fine tip sharpie
3. Get a pipe jig you can clamp to your drill press table.  Center it under the bit by lowering the chuck & bit down into the jig as you bolt it down.

[image: drill press pipe jig]

4. Make a reference mark on the edge of the where it contacts the pipe.
5. Lay the pipe in the jig, adjust the the proper horizontal position, and align the line on the pipe with the mark on the jig.
6. Drill!

You could do this with the jig and a hand drill.  The problems are getting the center of the pipe for the initial hole, and then keeping the drill straight enough when you punch through the other side.  It depends on how accurate you need it.

Comment: I don't need it super accurate.   I still think I'm better off drilling the two holes separately.   Then I don't need to worry about the bit being that straight.  I just need to somehow make two diametrically-opposite lines with their ends at the same point on the circumference.

Comment: Drilling from both sides opens up alot of room for error/inaccuracy.  Maybe you could share what you're doing with this.  That would help us understand your accuracy requirement.  Anyway, if you want exactly opposite lines down the length of the pipe, strike the first line as I described in #2 above.  Then use a center finding jig like this: https://www.amazon.com/Robert-Larson-800-2875-Plastic-Center/dp/B000CD1T0A to mark the other side.  Then repeat #2 with the new mark aligned with the edge of the lumber.

Comment: I have edited the OP question, adding a PS to describe my application.